# Custom ListView in SharePoint 2013 app

Tags: listview, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps, sharepoint-branding

I created a list in a SharePoint 2013 App and the Schema.xml contains the following node related to the AllItems view.

```
    <View BaseViewID="1" 
    Type="HTML" 
    WebPartZoneID="Main" 
    DisplayName="$Resources:core,objectiv_schema_mwsidcamlidC24;" 
    DefaultView="TRUE" 
    OrderedView="TRUE" 
    MobileView="TRUE" 
    MobileDefaultView="TRUE" 
    SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" 
    ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/generic.png?rev=23" 
    Url="AllItems.aspx">
```

I'd like to replace `SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx` with my own page, so I can brand it as per my client's requirements. I've already created my `Pages\CustomViewPage.aspx`, but I cannot figure out how to reference my custom page.

I've tried the following attributes. I replaced `SetupPath` with `Path`, see [View Element (List)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms438338%28v=office.15%29.aspx):

```
    <View BaseViewID="1" 
    Type="HTML" 
    WebPartZoneID="Main" 
    DisplayName="$Resources:core,objectiv_schema_mwsidcamlidC24;" 
    DefaultView="TRUE" 
    OrderedView="TRUE" 
    MobileView="TRUE" 
    MobileDefaultView="TRUE" 
    Path="~site/pages/customviewpage.aspx" 
    ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/generic.png?rev=23" 
    Url="AllItems.aspx">
```

If I use `Path="~site/pages/customviewpage.aspx"` or `Path="../pages/customviewpage.aspx"`, the application cannot be deployed and the error is not very helpful (SharePoint Online):

```
    @"Error 1
    CorrelationId: aedf6556-ac09-4b0e-9367-905c81563a57
    ErrorDetail: There was a problem with activating the app web definition.
    ErrorType: App
    ErrorTypeName: App Related
    ExceptionMessage: <nativehr>0x80131600</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
    Source: AppWeb
    SourceName: App Web Deployment
    Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': 
    Failed to install app for SharePoint. Please see the output window for details.
```

If you know how to reference your own custom ListView page, please drop me a line. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, it's not exactly what I was looking for, but it will do for now.

1. I had the `Pages\CustomViewPage.aspx` under the folder `Pages`, then I moved my custom page to `Lists\MyList\CustomViewPage.aspx`.
2. Right-click `Lists\MyList\CustomViewPage.aspx` and select **Properties**.
3. Set **Deployment Type: ElementFile**.
4. Then set the `View` tag as follows. Please note the attribute `SetupPath` was replaced with `Path`:

   ```
   <View BaseViewID="1" 
   Type="HTML" 
   WebPartZoneID="Main" 
   DisplayName="$Resources:core,objectiv_schema_mwsidcamlidC24;" 
   DefaultView="TRUE" 
   OrderedView="TRUE" 
   MobileView="TRUE" 
   MobileDefaultView="TRUE" 
   Path="customviewpage.aspx" 
   ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/generic.png?rev=23" 
   Url="AllItems.aspx">
   ```

It's obvious the issue was related to the path which was incorrect. The workaround above places the custom form in the same folder as the list. If you know a way to reference a file on another folder, please drop me a line.

Comment: Please consider marking your answer as the answer to your own question. That way, people will see that your question has an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. All the view pages inside SharePoint List is created directly under the SharePoint List path. The Pages library is meant for the current site scope. You cannot use the Pages library pages as the list view page. It's the relative path issue and whatever you have implemented is correct!